# Reference for homotopy colimits

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory, model-categories

In the first paragraph of the following paper [by Heuts and Moerdijk](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.0704.pdf) they speak of

> A well known construction of homotopy colimits
>   $$h_{!}:sSet^A \rightarrow sSet/NA$$

$A$ is small category. $sSet$ is category of simplicial set. What is this construction?

I would be happy for any references.

Comment: I don't know enough to say more but Dan Dugger's notes on homotopy colimits are quite nice and likely could help https://pages.uoregon.edu/ddugger/hocolim.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is literally explained two lines below.

> It maps a diagram $F$ to the simplicial set $h_!(F)$ with as $n$-simplices the pairs $(x,a_0 \to \dots \to a_n)$ consisting of an $n$-simplex $a_0 \to \dots \to a_n$ in $NA$ and an $n$-simplex $x$ in $F(a_0)$.

It's probably instructive to try to compute this for the case of pushouts ($A = \bullet \gets \bullet \to \bullet$).

A possible reference is Chapter 14 in *Model categories and their localizations* by Hirschhorn. The thing you want is derived from what is denoted there by $B(- \downarrow A)$. It's a kind of bar construction. Proposition 14.8.9 says that $B(- \downarrow A)$ is a fibrant resolution of the constant diagram; it follows that homotopy colimits can be computed by the recipe given by Heuts and Moerdijk, which is the coend $\int^{a \in A} B(a \downarrow A) \times F(a)$ (this is probably explained somewhere in Hirschhorn's book, probably in a different chapter, but I can't track it down right now).

Comment: I did see this, sorry if I am unclear, what I am asking for is the general theory behind this construction - if there is.

Comment: @W.Zhan I've added a possible reference.

Comment: @W.Zhan Sorry, there was a slight mistake in my previous edit; I had inverted $B(- \downarrow A)$ with $B(A \downarrow -)$.

Comment: Apologies if I'm misreading the tone, but the snark in your first line is unnecessary.